# iOS Screen capture but not blocking main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, quartz-2d

Apple has given a source code to capture screen here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html

However, if I constantly capture, the UI would get really slow when ever it does renderincontext.  When I tried to dispatch it to a different thread, it would work for a while, but crashes due to memory leaks. The reason is that SOME of the UIKit calls it uses are not thread safe and can only be used in main thread.

I'm looking for a different way to capture screen without the use of UIKIT and use purely Quartz2d instead.  Here is what I did but when it captures, it becomes upside down and the image is doubled side by side and the image is VERY small around 1/6 of the screen if using iPAD retina:

```
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
size_t bytesPerRow = imageSize.width * 5;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, imageSize.width, imageSize.height, 5, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
{
    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
    [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

}

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

Does anyone know how create a proper context with right scale and proper coordinate translation?

Or what is wrong with my code?

Or is there a better way to do this out of main thread?

Thanks